# Expor um objeto ( baseado no request ) para toda aplicação

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Opa, não sei se é possivel fazer oque quero, mas vamos lá:

Tenho uma api em lumen que basicamente ler um header especifico do request e faz parse num arquivo YAML e transforma isso num array, só que como eu uso isto em varios controllers e classes diferentes eu fiz um função que recebe este header e  retorna o array, porem estou tendo que repetir isto em todo controller / classe, oque eu quero é:

Transformar essa "função" em algo global que eu possa chamar de qualquer método / classe tipo assim:

```
public function verifyemail(Cliente $cliente) {
  $email = $cliente->email
}
```

Onde cliente é a função que me retorna o array.

Tipo como o app() que eu posso usar em qualquer lugar:

```
app()->environment() == 'development'
```

Acho que fui claro, se não, me perguntem.

Comment: Não é só você criar a função em um arquivo separado e depois dar um `include` nos arquivos?

Comment: Mas digo usando alguma feature do laravel / lumen, igual uma vez que li sobre Services Providers mas nao consegui entender direito

Comment: Já pensou em adicionar esse método num `Controller` personalizado e depois alterar todos os `Controllers` a seguir para herdar dessa classe. Ou apenas crie uma nova classe e adicione essa função de forma estática para essa classe, e adicione ele em algum [Service Provider](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers) caso queira torna-lo um singleton.

Comment: A questão é esse Service provider pode depender de request ? pq esta minha logica depende do header que recebo no request

Comment: Acredito que toda classe que você define no Laravel tem acesso aos seus `helpers`, logo, você obteria os dados do `header` ao pegar todos os dados da requisição usando o `helper` [`request`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-request).

Comment: Caso o Lumen não dê suporte ao `helper` `request`, você pode passar o `helper` `app` no construtor da classe pelo `Service Provider` e salva-lá na classe. Há também a possibilidade de apenas adicionar um [`binding`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container#binding) no `AppServiceProvider`, assim você não precisa criar um `Service Provider`. Depois, use `app(ClasseComAFunção::class)` para obter uma instância da classe no seu `Controller`, [documentação](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.6/container).

Answer (score 1):

acho q nesse caso a melhor solução é colocar esse método no arquivo `Controller.php` e então todos os outros controllers da sua aplicação que extendem essa classe podem usar essa metodo normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Cria em App/Helpers um Helper da maneira que precisa exemplo:

```
<?php


namespace App\Helpers;


class ClienteHelper
{

    // Sua função estática
    static function verifyEmail(Cliente $cliente) 
    {
         $email = $cliente->email
    }
}
```

Aí você poderá chamar de qualquer parte do código assim:

```
return ClienteHelper::verifyEmail($cliente_xpto);
```